# Proof that $A\subseteq B\implies\Bbb P(A) \le\Bbb P(B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have to prove that $A\subseteq B\implies\Bbb P(A) \le\Bbb P(B)$, where $\Bbb P$ is probability.

So far I have learned about direct proof, mathematical induction and proof by contraposition.

This exact proposition is solved in my literature (*Elementare Einführung in die Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung* by Karl Bosch), but it isn't explained at all and I don't want to copy sth. I don't understand.

Which method should I choose and how is it done?

Thanks!

(c means "is subset of")

Comment: Do you know that probability is ($\sigma$-) *additive* and always nonnegative? It easily follows from these, as we have $$P(B)=P(A)+P(B\setminus A)$$

Comment: The whole thing in words:
"If A is a subset of B it is implied that the probability of A is smaller or the same as the probability of B"

Comment: @Berci is that a valid proof for my proposition? And if so, why?

Either way, it's good to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\subseteq B\rightarrow N(A)\leq N(B)\rightarrow \frac{N(A)}{N(\Omega)}\leq \frac{N(B)}{N(\Omega)}\rightarrow P(A)\leq P(B)$.

Comment: Thanks! I was very close to this answer. I just didn't know that I have to write N(A) instead of just A but as I understand it, it means "the number of Elements in A".

Doesn't mean the other answers are wrong/less helpful, but this the one I understand best.

So thanks to everyone!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help. Yes $N(A)$ is the number of Elements in A.

Answer (score 3):

Probability is a kind of measure measuring the size of sets, which are called events. And basically, measure requires two properties. One, non-negative; Two, measure of disjoint union of sets equals to sum of measures of each set. Write in language of probability, for any disjoint events $A,B$, we have
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)\geq0$$

So, if $A\subseteq B$, then
$$P(B)=P(A\cup(B/A))=P(A)+P(B/A)\geq P(A)$$